# Different behaviour for local and productive WeblogicServer

Tags: caching, weblogic

.
Hey guys,

I have a strange behaviour and am wondering why this happens:

My managed bean holds three values (selected plant, selected year and selected month). When opening the required page a `@PostConstruct method` is called and initializes the plant data according to the selected/pre defined plant, year and month. When changing one of these three options data should be updated and displayed via AJAX request. In order to switch to edit mode I can click my button and change one value from true to fals which is indicating whether the page should be displayed in view or edit mode.

Now here is my problem:
My local Weblogic Server (IntegratedWeblogicServer - standard configuration) works as expected. I open the page, see my current data, switch to edit mode, edit & save it. That's all. Works like a charm.

The productive Weblogic Server (configured by a colleague of mine) does some kind of cache I think. I open the page, see my current data, change year value to last year and see the updated values. When clicking on the "edit" button the old values are displayed instead of the updated values. This just happens as long as I do not switch the plant. My current workaround looks like this: open the page, switch the plant and then switch the year. After switching the plant everything works like expected. I can't figure out why the productive machine behaves different than the local machine. Each of the update methods setPlant(), setYear() and setMonth() call refreshValues() and are equal requading JSF definitions. So I don't know if it's a caching problem or maybe a Weblogic configuration problem.

Let me know if you need more information or certain code snippets. I excluded them as it is a lot of code.

Kind regards,
Stefi

Answer (score 0):

Enable http headers debug from browser and monitor the difference in each environment. Also monitor the access.log on each domains server.